# Update the column of a selected gridview row in visual studio 14?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Button Code

```
Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Mysqlconnection = New SqlConnection
    Mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = "Server=CTJY\SQLSERVER;Database=WinningAcademyDB;Integrated Security=true;"

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Mysqlconnection.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "update Grade set Girdview4_col3 = '" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "' "

    command = New SqlCommand(query, Mysqlconnection)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader
End Sub
```

Every time I click the button, all in the Grade columns is changed and is all the same. I only want the selected item's Grade to be changed. Not all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **where** to select those grids.. that is, create a function regarding event on cell select in datagrid and populate a string for **where clause** of **sql** statement..